# Remove chars in beginning of string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am opening up a txt file and writing it to a string array. The issue is how is do I do the equivalent of a string, `lines.Remove(0,6)` with a string array? I know I have to loop through each [] in the array but then how do I get my desired result?

text file:

> 12345;9/19/2016 something.pdf

how I'm getting the file:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\ecmvmdev21\text.txt");
```

Desired output:

> 9/19/2016 something.pdf

Comment: Do you want only the last line or do you want to remove part of the first line in that file? Show the sample line(s) of that file.

Comment: If you're reading all of these lines *and* also need to do something to each, to me it makes more sense to use something like a `StreamReader` and modifying the lines as you store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array of strings as you said, then inside your for loop:

`lines[i] = lines[i].Substring(6);`

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was simple just wasn't sure if a .remove or substring would work with an array element.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you will always have 6 unwanted chars at the beginning of each line then you can do it like this:

```
lines = lines.Select(x => x.Substring(6)).ToArray();
```

[String.Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ReadAllLines` you are getting an array where each item represents a row in the file.

To do what you want you can:

- Use instead `.ReadAllText` and then you will receive a single `string` containing all the text (on which you can use the `.Remove`)
- Go to `lines[0]` and on that do `.Remove`. Remember to check that you have an item at position `0` otherwise you will receive `indexOutOfRangeException`
- If you want to do this for all the lines then you can use linq's `.Select`:

  ```
  lines = lines.Select(line => line.Remove(0,6));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and Select to remove the first six characters from each line, eg:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\ecmvmdev21\text.txt")
                     .Select(line=>line.Remove(0,6))
                     .ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(@"\\ecmvmdev21\text.txt")
                     .Select(line=>line.Remove(0,6))
                     .ToArray();
```

The difference is that `ReadLines` returns an IEnumerable instead of `string[]` which means that it doesn't load all lines in memory before executing `Select`. Lines are loaded as needed. This results in better memory utilization

Answer (score 1):

```
lines[0] = lines[0].substr(6);
```